# valid json file from php/mysql

Tags: php, json

i've spend so many time in the net for learning google api v3 from php /mysql but no way.so i begin again asking for validate all the process
First my json file, looks like that

```
{"lat":"46.8529510","lng":"0.5433920","ec_nom":"ANTRAN","ec_type":"ECOLE ELEM","ec_adresse":"PLACE DE L EGLISE","ec_ville":"ANTRAN","ec_cp":"86100"}
```

all the json file, i've seen looks like

```
**name[**{"lat":"46.8529510","lng":"0.5433920","ec_nom":"ANTRAN","ec_type":"ECOLE ELEM","ec_adresse":"PLACE DE L EGLISE","ec_ville":"ANTRAN","ec_cp":"86100"}**]**
```

My code

```
 $cherch_coordon=mysql_query("SELECT lat, lng,      ec_nom,ec_type,ec_adresse,ec_ville,ec_cp from mouv_0910 WHERE type_nomin='TD' AND oui_mouvement>0  ORDER BY ec_ville ");
$combien=mysql_num_rows($cherch_coordon) ;

  while ($trouv=mysql_fetch_object($cherch_coordon))
        {

          $en_jason=json_encode($trouv) ;
       //$erreur_json=last_error($en_jason);
         echo"$en_jason" ;
```

So is my json file's valid?

Comment: Are the `*`s part of the JSON?  You cannot bold/italicize text inside code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode` *always* prints valid JSON.

`{}` is for an object, `[]` is for an array.

P.S.

```
name[{"lat":"46.8529510","lng":"0.5433920","ec_nom":"ANTRAN","ec_type":"ECOLE ELEM","ec_adresse":"PLACE DE L EGLISE","ec_ville":"ANTRAN","ec_cp":"86100"}]
```

Is *not* valid JSON, or vaid anything for that matter.

Did you mean this (note the `()` instead of `[]`)?

```
name({"lat":"46.8529510","lng":"0.5433920","ec_nom":"ANTRAN","ec_type":"ECOLE ELEM","ec_adresse":"PLACE DE L EGLISE","ec_ville":"ANTRAN","ec_cp":"86100"})
```

This is JSONP, not JSON.

Comment: is my file as it is, is valid on javascript request for google maps marker ou should it have this form name({"lat":"46.8529510","lng":"0.5433920",.....,})

Comment: THANKS FOR THE SPEED OF THE ANSWER